# PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher is not working

Tags: android, formatting, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to use PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher but there is nothing happening as if the code is not there

here is the code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
    EditText PhoneEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    PhoneEdit.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
}
```

when entering 002010555666 it still the same no - or + or (), just the same without any formatting
is there anything missing in the code

help

Comment: on which device you are trying it?

Answer (score 20):

Have had the same issue, but after removing `android:digits="1234567890+"` it gone.

Comment: This was my issue - I had to have the input type of phone, than I removed the digits as well.

Comment: Ran into this issue as well, but instead of removing it I just modified it to `android:digits="1234567890+()-"`

Comment: @DanielNugent I suggest to add also a space, cause some international formats use it:
`android:digits="1234567890 +()-"`

Comment: Why 'android:digits' makes the problem? How should I fix that?

Comment: @shaithana and DanielNugent Thanks a lot guys. I was searching for this solution for like an hour.

Answer (score 5):

I added a comment to YTerle's answer, but I wanted to put the complete answer below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLength="14"
                android:id="@+id/phone" />
```

Then in the code put the following:

```
phoneView.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Comment: It will not work if you set `android:digits="0123456789"` to EditText to allow only certain digits/characters.

Answer (score 4):

I was having issues even after adding `android:inputType="phone"` in the XML.

The solution was to **set the Language in the phone**:

> Settings -> Search for Language -> pick English (United States)

The format (999) 999-9999 is mostly used in the US, therefore the phone language should be set to that only.

Comment: You can also use country code in the PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher constructor, e.g. `new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US")`, if you only support phone numbers from the specific country.

Comment: I didn't know `android:inputType="phone"` was needed for this, thanks! Now it's working

Answer (score 3):

Final Solution: The issue is only associated with the android:inputType you selected in XML. It won't work with the "number". You need to choose "phone" or no inputType.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in an application and it worked just fine in the emulator (Android_4.2_Emulator_Smartphone_Nexus_S using Platform 4.4.2, API 19) but had no effect at all when run on my Samsung Tab 3 device running Platform 4.1.2, API 17.  Maybe it's device dependent?  The documentation indicates it was introduced in API 1 so I would think it should have all the kinks worked out by now but evidently not.